# Activity not opening android while passing image (nothing happens)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two activities and I am passing image to the second activity after capturing the image. Somehow the second activity does not open and the process stays at activity 1. There is no error and no exceptions being thrown.

Activity 1:

```
var image = textureView.Bitmap;


            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, memStream);

            imageByte = memStream.ToArray();
            Intent i = new Intent(this.Context, typeof(Demo.Droid.CameraDisplay));
            i.PutExtra("image", imageByte);
            activity.StartActivity(i);
```

Activity 2:

```
byte[] Image = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("image");


        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Image, 0, Image.Length);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();

        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

P.S: It worked once but after that it stayed on the activity 1.

Comment: if you don't use `PutExtra` than opening activity?

Comment: Does the debugger hit the onCreate method of the other Activity?